# Accessing to kubernetes from pod using java api, returns forbbiden error

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-apiserver

I want to connect to kubernetes api from a pod using the java kubernetes library. But when I try to do anything with the api, kubernetes returns Forbbiden error.

Here is the code of how I connect.

```
ApiClient client = ClientBuilder.cluster().build();
Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client);
CoreV1Api api = new CoreV1Api();
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to connect properly to kubernetes?

*Kubernetes is running with minikube

Thanks so much for reading!!

Comment: Most likely the issue is not with the code itself, but with the Service Account of the pod. (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#use-the-default-service-account-to-access-the-api-server). Are you sure your pod has a service account with the right permissions. The default service account might not have the right permissions (or automount might be disabled).

Comment: I have the same issue and have set a service account with the correct permissions for the pod. However it does not look like this is the service account that the code end up using. Can someone help?